# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" when using namespace defined in header

Tags: c++

Environment: MacOS

Compiler version: C++20

I'm new to C++, and I'm writing a `ForceInit.h` file, and call it in the `MainFunc.cpp`.

In `ForceInit.h`:

```
#ifndef FORCE_INIT_H
#  define FORCE_INIT_H

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace hw32 {
    struct ForceInit {
        ForceInit() {
            if (count == 0) {
                count = 1;
                ios_base::Init();
            }
        }
        private:
            static int count;
    };
    static ForceInit forceinit;
}

#endif
```

In `MainFunc.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "forceinit.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace hw32;


// Driver Code
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me error:

```
Build finished with errors(s):
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN4hw329ForceInit5countE", referenced from:
      __ZN4hw329ForceInitC1Ev in ccGyt5tf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I would like to know what's wrong with the code in the header file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in the header file. The problem is missing code in main.cpp. You haven't defined `hw32::ForceInit::count` only declared it. Add the following to main.cpp `int hw32::ForceInit::count = 0;`

Comment: @john awesome! It works!! Thanks!!